# How to make custom tags in dust.js

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js

i am using [klei-dust](https://github.com/klei/dust) templating engine in my project built with express framework. I want to change its opening and closing tags.

Is their any way in dust.js to make such kind of change.

I want to change `{ }` into `<% %>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, edit your copy of `dust.pegjs` and change the definitions for `ld` and `rd`:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/master/src/dust.pegjs#L234

Then run `grunt build` and a new copy of Dust with your changes will be built into the `tmp` directory.